# jQuery and "this" management? How to avoid variable collisions?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you are writing complex jQuery/javascript, how do you manage using `this` without re-defining `this` variables that were previously defined? Do you have a rule of thumb or a personal preference for naming your `this` variables (as the nesting gets deeper)?

There are times where I want variables from a higher scope to be available to nested functions/callbacks, but then there are times when I'd like to have a clean slate/scope; is there a good way to call functions/callbacks without having to worry about variable collisions? If so, what technique(s) do you use?

---

Some super silly test code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    console.warn('start');

    var $this = $(this),

    $dog = $('#dog'),

    billy = function() {

        console.log('BILLY!', 'THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog);

        var $this = $(this);

        console.log('BILLY!', 'THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog);

    };

             // (#1)
    billy(); // BILLY! THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
             // BILLY! THIS: jQuery(Window /demos/this/) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

    console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // THIS: jQuery(Document /demos/this/) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

             // (#2)
    billy(); // BILLY! THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
             // BILLY! THIS:  jQuery(Window /demos/this/) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

    $('#foo').slideUp(function() {

                                                          // (#3)
        console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // BILLY! THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

        var $this = $(this); // (#10)

                                                          // (#4)
        console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // BILLY! THIS: jQuery(Window /demos/this/) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

    });

    $('#clickme').click(function() {

                                                          // (#5)
        console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

        var $this = $(this);

                                                          // (#6)
        console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // THIS: jQuery(button#clickme) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

        $('#what').animate({
            opacity : 0.25,
            left    : '+=50',
            height  : 'toggle'
        }, 500, function() {

                                                              // (#7)
            console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

            var $this = $(this);

                                                              // (#8)
            console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // THIS: jQuery(div#what) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

        });

    });

             // (#9)
    billy(); // THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
             // THIS: jQuery(div#foo) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)

    console.warn('finish');

});
```

[A full demo page can be found here (jsbin.com)](http://jsbin.com/oyegag/3).

**Note:** As you can see, I've "marked" the comments with numbers (#XX) for easy reference.

---

### Observation 1:

**Marker (#1)**

```
BILLY! THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
```

**Rhetorical question:** Why is `$this` undefined, but `$dog` is accessible?

**Answer:** Because the `var` within that scope is re-defining `$this`; it's just that I'm trying to log `$this` before its been defined within that scope.

If I comment out `var $this = $(this);`, then the **marker (#1)** returns:

```
BILLY! THIS: jQuery(Document index2.html) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
BILLY! THIS: jQuery(Document index2.html) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
```

The same logic applies to **markers (#2), (#3), (#4), (#5), (#6), (#7) and (#8)**.

Based on this observation (and please correct me if I'm wrong here) I'm assuming that I could put `var $this = $(this);` at the bottom of the function, and the current scope would know that I want to use the current scope's `$this` (even though it's not defined yet), and not the parent's `$this` (even though it **IS** defined).

#### POSSIBLE SOLUTION TO AVOIDING `$this` CONFLICTS:

If one wants to cache `$(this)` outside/within other closures/functions/callbacks and avoid collisions, then one should use different variable labels like these (for example):

```
var $$ = $(this);
var $this2 = $(this);
var $t = $(this);
var $that = $(this);
```

#### QUESTION:

Is the solution above how you would avoid `$this` collisions? If not, what's your prefered technique?

---

### Observation 2:

**Marker (#9)**

```
THIS: undefined | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
```

... `$this` is undefined for reasons mentioned above, but:

```
THIS: jQuery(div#foo) | DOG: jQuery(p#dog)
```

... `$this` is now `$('#foo')`!

#### QUESTION(S):

Exactly why did this happen?

Is it because `$this` was re-defined via **marker (#10)**?

(Hmmm, I feel like I need to Google "garbage collection in javascript".)

Again, when writing complex jquery/javascript, what's the best way to avoid this type of variable collision?

---

*I hope these aren't horrible questions. Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me out. :)*

Comment: If i had multiple $(this) vars cached, i would name them what they are. for example, if it's a ul, name it $ul, li, $li, etc.

Comment: Thanks for tip @KevinB! I've normally used that naming convention when caching elements; I never thought to apply the same thinking for when it comes to caching "this". Thanks!

Comment: For example, if I needed to maintain someone else's code and came across an arbitrary `$$`, I'd be annoyed because I would then then have to search the code to figure out what it references (or log it, etc). If it were instead named `$wrapper` I would know right away that it was the wrapper.

Comment: Ahhhhhh, I totally get that now! Thank you for the clarification. I'm going to experiment with this idea tonight... I've spent all these years using `$this` or `$$`, I'm not sure why I never thought to do what you suggest. Great tip!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The behavior you are seeing when redeclaring `var $this` in an inner scope is called [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting).  It's one of the reasons why you should always have a single `var` statement at the start of each scope for any variables you need in that scope -- not that it's *necessary*, it's just clearer because it does the same thing and the variable names are easier to locate.

As for having to use a variable in deeply nested scopes .. that may be a sign that something is wrong (too much nesting, single responsibility, etc.).  If you need to use certain constructs a lot, consider adding them to the scope of an object instead of giving them names that end with `2`.  At the very least you should give them descriptive names (I usually only use `$this = $(this)` within a single scope, and that's to avoid having to call `$()` repeatedly).  `self` is often used to refer to the current object within function definitions inside of its own scope.

```
var Dog = function (boy, dog) {
    this.boy = boy;
    this.dog = dog;
    this.$clickme = $("#clickme");
}

Dog.prototype.bind = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.$clickme.on('click', function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        console.log('THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', self.dog);

        $('#what').animate({
            opacity : 0.25,
            left    : '+=50',
            height  : 'toggle'
        }, 500, function() {
            var $this = $(this);
            console.log('CLICKME:', self.$clickme, ' | ', 'DOG:', self.dog);
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: Omg, "hoisting" blows my mind. I can't believe I've gone all of these years without knowing about it. I'm reading article now and digesting your detailed reply and awesome code sample. After I play with your code tonight, I may be back with a few questions. Thank you! +1

Comment: I like this tip, found in the article you linked to: **"I strongly recommend that you have exactly one var statement per scope, and that it be at the top. If you force yourself to do this, you will never have hoisting-related confusion. However, doing this can make it hard to keep track of which variables have actually been declared in the current scope. I recommend using JSLint with the onevar option to enforce this."** (I'm gonna give that a try).

Comment: I'm also playing with the `"latedef": true` option via [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/docs/).

Comment: `"shadow": false` is also very helpful: **"This option suppresses warnings about variable shadowing i.e. declaring a variable that had been already declared somewhere in the outer scope."**

Answer (score 8):

You're actually running into variable hoisting issue:

```
billy = function() {

    console.log('BILLY!', 'THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog);

    var $this = $(this);

    console.log('BILLY!', 'THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog);

};
```

is actually interpreted at runtime like this:

```
billy = function() {

    var $this;

    console.log('BILLY!', 'THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog); // $this hasn't been set to anything yet...

    $this = $(this);

    console.log('BILLY!', 'THIS:', $this, ' | ', 'DOG:', $dog);

};
```

JavaScript hoists variable and function declarations to the top of the scope block so you can reference them before manually declaring them. This gets people into trouble when they reference vars of the same name from *outside* of the scope block, as you can clearly see in your example.

Comment: Hoisting. Wow, I'm so glad I asked for help on this one... I never knew that's how JS handled things. Amazing. Thanks so much for the reply and code sample and clarification. +1

Comment: I really like how you showed how hoisting works. I ran into this issue lately and this clarifies it big time!

Answer (score 4):

You've just encountered the joys of scope and JavaScript. One thing a lot of people like to do is, if you need access to the current scope in a callback, define this as self, like so:

```
var $ = require('jquery')
  , database = require('database')

$.on('click', function(action) {
  var self = this;
  database.connect(function() {
    database.putSync(self.action.button);
  });
});
```

Note that when 'connect' is called, the scope of "this" is reset to that of the callback and not the click-handler, which is why you've stored your scope in an accessible variable.

Comment: Awesome! I like the idea of using the variable name `self` (that's one I have not used much). Thanks so much for the tips and code example, it's very helpful. +1

Comment: Yeah, you just have to avoid callback hell. If your code is shallow, though, self is great :) http://callbackhell.com

Comment: For some reason I missed your link to [callbackhell.com](http://callbackhell.com/)! I did not realize I could name my inline anon functions! Short read but packed with useful tips. +1!

Answer (score 2):

Others already pointed out the hoisting trouble you experienced in your example. Still I think it is worth mentioning the proxy functionality of jQuery.

It comes in super-handy! You don't have to do stuff like `var self = this;`, which gives you trouble when nesting multiple scopes.

[jQuery proxy documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/)

With proxy, you can delegate `this` into your function, which is very useful if you are using object-oriented javascript in combination with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var $dog = $('#dog');
  // without proxy
  $('.billy').click(function () {
      // $(this) refers to the node that has been clicked 
      $(this).css('color', 'green');
  });

  // with proxy
  $('.billy').click($.proxy(function () {
     // $(this) refers to $dog
     $(this).css('backgroundColor', 'red');
  }, $dog));
});
```

Working example here: [jsFiddle jQuery proxy usage](http://jsfiddle.net/EEXEB/1/)

If you really need your `this` references side-by-side in a function, I suggest keeping them all loaded up in an array, so you don't have to worry about naming them, and you also keep score of your nesting level:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
  var thisStack = [];
  thisStack.push($('#dog'));

  $('.billy').click(function () {
    thisStack.push($this);
    // thisStack[0] refers to $('#dog')
    // thisStack[1] refers to $(this)

    ... more code ...

    thisStack.pop(); // get rid of $(this), leaving scope
  });
});
```

Comment: Awesome info! Thanks Justus, I was wondering if `$.proxy` would be useful in this situation. Thanks so much for the details/clarification/example on that. Also, it's really cool reading your take on using `[]`, that's a great technique! I never would have thought of that. :) +1! Much appreciated!!!

Comment: And `$.proxy` is now integrated on jQuery event-handlers, as @Zipp showed in his answer, so you don't have to wrap those functions with the proxy method.

Answer (score 1):

As above said. One popular way is to assign variable self to 'this'
Another way is to send the scope you want the function to be in as a last parameter:

```
this.on('change', function() {
 //this is now the scope outside the callback function.
}, this)
```

Comment: Whoa, that's cool! I did realize that could be done. Makes total sense now that you point it out. Thank you for the tip twibakish! +1! :)

Comment: Would [jQuery's `$.proxy`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/) also do the same thing? If so, is there an advantage to using one example over the other? I'm still trying to grasp `$.proxy` so maybe it's not the same thing (it looks similar to what your example is doing though). Thanks again!

Comment: It looks like they made the proxy-functionality usable without  the need to specify it. If you need to grasp the concept of proxy, see my answer.